# Pasar una variable de una condicional a otra PHP

Tags: php

Mediante un `isset` tengo una variable con  información dentro de una condicional, cuando le doy submit al formulario la variable sale indefinida:

> Notice: Undefined variable: previus

¿Como hago para guardar la información de esa variable y pasarla a otra condicional?

```
 <?php
     if (isset($_POST['previus'])) {
         $previus = $_POST['previus']; 
     }

     if (isset($_POST['categoria1'])) {     
         $upCat1 = new Controller();
         $upCat1->actualizarDato($_POST['categoria1'],'categorias','categoria1',$previus);
     }
 ?>
```

Actualizar dato lo que hace es mandar la información al controlador y posteriormente al modelo, donde se realiza el update de los datos, $previus es el valor anterior para ejecutar:

```
UPDATE $tabla SET $dato = :value WHERE $dato = :previus
```

Sigo teniendo problemas para pasar la variable a otra condicional a pesar de sus ayudas.

Comment: Falta que expliques que tiene tu clase `Controller` y que hace exactamente `actualizarDato`, pero en general si quieres compartir en una variable de una página `PHP` a otra, lo que debes hacer es: enviar un parámetro en el URL, si es un formulario colocar un `input hidden` o crear un `cookie`

Comment: Hola, si pones $_POST['previus'] significa que este PHP recibe un parámetro POST, el mensaje de error, confirma que no es así.

Comment: Hola Srsole, el parámetro post si lo recibe, por ejemplo al recibirlo puedo hacer header("location: $previus.php"); pero el problema es que al darle submit al formulario deja de existir y no he podido solucionarlo, ya intenté con el input hidden pero me dió problemas

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentarlo verificando si están definidas las dos variables para realizar la operación actualizarDato

ejemplo:

```
 if (isset($_POST['previus'])&&isset($_POST['categoria1'])) {
      $previus= $_POST['previus']; 
      $upCat1 = new Controller();
      $upCat1->actualizarDato($_POST['categoria1'],'categorias','categoria1',$previus);
 }
```

espero sea de ayuda,
falta dar mas datos en tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes dejar como global el *scope* de la variable `$previus` sacándola del cuerpo del primer `if` estableciendo con el operador de fusión null `??` 2 posibles valores; el primero si tiene uno asignado y el segundo a `sin valor` para que de este modo evitemos el error de: **Undefined**

```
$previus = $_POST['previus'] ?? 'sin valor';
```

De modo que el valor se mantiene para cuando lo requieres en tu segunda sentencia `if` así:

> Con lo anterior el valor que sea que tome tu variable `$previus` debería estar disponible para usar después.

- [Operador de fusión null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php)

Answer (score 0):

La variable `$previus` solo existe en el ambito dentro del `if`. Asi que es recommendable definirla antes de usarla:

```php
$previus = ''; //asi la variable estara disponible para el resto del codigo

if (isset($_POST['previus'])) {
    $previus = $_POST['previus']; 
}

/...
```

Comment: Creí que funcionaría, pero ahora la variable sale como vacía y no se mantiene luego de definirla y modificarla